# Dragging image from NSView to Finder. Alternative to dragImage:at:offset:event:pasteboard:source:slideBack:

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop

I've been using `dragImage:at:offset:event:pasteboard:source:slideBack:` to show an image representation while dragging in previous projects but now that method is deprecated.

I've read that the supposed alternative is using `beginDraggingSessionWithItems(…)` but, the thing is I can't manage to do it properly.

This is my case:

-If I use `dragPromisedFilesOfTypes(…)`, everything works ok. I drag my image to any folder, I can name the file as I want using `namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination(…)`, etc, BUT the dragged image is just an icon and I can't provide a dragging image since the aforementioned method is not longer available.

-If I use `beginDraggingSessionWithItems(…)` instead, I can provide a dragging image in `mouseDragged(theEvent)` method BUT then nothing happens when I drop the image into Finder. I could use 
`draggingSession(_:endedAtPoint:operation:)` method to save the image manually when the operation ends but this method doesn't have any info about drop destination url and `namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination(…)` is not called in this case.

So, what am I missing? I guess this is a simple operation and shouldn't be that complicated. Apple documentation and googled tutorials are always using the deprecated method so I don't have any valid example to see where is my mistake. Please help.

Comment: This post helped me very much. I hope it helps you as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781982/implement-drag-from-nsimageview-and-save-image-to-a-file/7830739#comment59964018_7830739

Comment: Thank you for answering, Rocky. In fact, that's the way I used to do source dragging delegate. Unfortunately, that way is not longer allowed since the `dragimage...` function has been marked unavailable (at least using Swift and targeting 10.10). That's why I'm asking

Comment: Same here. Couldn't find a solution for Swift. Has anybody looked into macOS 10.12?

Comment: The "What's New in Cocoa" WWDC 2016 Session talks about the move of promissed drags to the new item based API. Starts around Minute 24:12.